# Trying to close a form after the next one is shown in C# cf

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

I've been studying Android lately and I tried to port one of its functions to C# compact framework.

What I did is create an Abstract class that I call Activity.
This class looks like this

```
  internal abstract class Activity
  {
      protected Form myForm;
      private static Activity myCurrentActivity = null;
      private static Activity myNextActivity = null;

      internal static void LoadNext(Activity nextActivity)
      {
         myNextActivity = nextActivity;
         if (myNextActivity != null)
         {
            myNextActivity.Show();
            if (myCurrentActivity != null)
            {
               myCurrentActivity.Close();
               myCurrentActivity = null;
            }
            myCurrentActivity = myNextActivity;
            myNextActivity = null;
         }
      }

      internal void Show()
      {
        //PROBLEM IS HERE
         Application.Run(myForm);
         //myForm.Show();
         //myForm.ShowDialog();
        //
      }

      internal void Close()
      {
         myForm.Close();
      }


      internal void GenerateForm()
      {
      ///Code that uses the Layout class to create a form, and then stores it in myForm
      //then attaches click handlers on all the clickable controls in the form
      //it is besides the point in this problem
      }

      protected abstract void Click(Control control);
      //this receives all the click events from all the controls in the form
      //it is besides the point in this problem

   }
```

The problem I have is with running the part of the `Show()` command

Basically all my classes implement the above class, load an xml file and display it.
When I want to transition to a new class/form (for example going from ACMain to ACLogIn)
I use this code

```
Activity.LoadNext(new ACLogIn);
```

Which is supposed to load the next form, show it , and unload the current form

I have tried these solutions (in the `Show()` method) and here is the problem with each one

1. using `myForm.ShowDialog()`

   This works, but blocks execution, which means that the old form does not close, and the more I move between the forms the more the process stack increases
2. using `myForm.Show()`

   This works, closes the old form after the old one is shown, but immediately after that closes the program and terminates it
3. using `Application.Run(myForm)`

   This works only on the first form loaded, when I move to the next form, it shows it then throws an exception saying "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Can someone help me fix this or find an alternative?

Comment: The main issue would be that you can only have 1 Main Form. See if Aplication has a writable MainForm property, then use that with Show().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're really after creating your own framework for this navigation, you need to re-work you thinking.  The Form instance passed into `Application.Run` must never close - when it does, Application.Run finishes execution and (typically) your `static void Main` entry point exits and the app terminates.

What I would propose is that you change your Activity to either being a UserControl:

```
public abstract class Activity : UserControl
{
  .... 
}
```

or Composing one

```
public abstract class Activity
{
    private UserControl m_control;
  .... 
}
```

Then instead of closing and showing Forms, parent *all* of the Activities inside the main Form as a container.

As fair warning, this is going to get complex when you start wanting to show things in a Tab motif instead of a Stack, or having split views.  Frameworks seem simple to create, but they're not so I'd at least consider using something already done unless you have compelling reasons to want to roll your own.

Comment: that idea my friend, is actually brilliant, it makes me feel extremely stupid for not thinking about it, it may actually be better than my idea of opening a new form before closing the next one

Comment: I have made all the necessary changes to my project in order to incorporate your idea
I am now showing just one form and add a Panel (I went with panel) instead of a form to it (as I said I'm using compact framework, so things are a bit weird here) and after adding it I remove the old one and it works perfectly, the process stack is always empty , and further more, the load times were cut in half.
Again a million thanks. now how can I give you a bazzilion stars? hmm I'll figure it out (:

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Run` is generally used with the overload that takes a `Form` parameter.  This would be the "main" form that would be responsible for starting/showing other forms.  This "main" form could be "hidden".  But, I think that's a little awkward.

Alternatively, you don't *need* a main form, you can use `Application.Run()` to start a message pump to process Windows messages; but, then the thread is busy processing messages and cannot show dialogs (they must be shown in the thread that is running `Application.Run`).  You can get around this by creating one or more form objects *before* calling `Application.Run` and these form objects could create a `Timer` object that would call `Form.Show()` or `Form.ShowDialog()` on the `Timer.Tick` event handler so that for form is shown after the call to `Run`.  I think this is a little awkward as well.

Both of these solutions kind of circumvent the way you're expected to use Windows and WinForms; so, I think you need to think about re-designing this application to work with the way that Windows and .NET works.